# In Fluent NHibernate how do I specify a dictionary mapping type size?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

How can I specify the size of the type used in the following Dictionary mapping:

```
HasMany(x => x.WidgetSettings)
                .AsMap<string>(idx => idx.Column("SettingKey"), 
                               elem => elem.Column("SettingValue"))
                .Not.LazyLoad()
                .Table("WidgetSettings");
```

The mapping defaults both column types to varchar(255) and I want the SettingValue colume to be nvarchar(MAX) for example. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

Seems this is a known bug in the 1.0 release.